# Too many packages when creating the virtualenv in Django with Anaconda

Tags: python, virtualenv

Is there any way to reset all packages in a new `virtualenv`?

Answer (score 0):

don't forget to activate your virtualenv before

```
pip freeze | xargs pip uninstall -y
```

OR

```
virtualenv --clear MYENV
```